# Jquery Countdown... time is running out

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I am trying to change the end of the countdown so it displays a countdown till the end date of 22nd of May 2014 on the below countdown, any idea how I do that?

Here is the webiste nordicitsourcing.com you will see it currently is counting down to a date I cannot even seem to find

Please help

Code here:

```
(function ($) {
    function Countdown() {
        this.regional = [];
        this.regional[''] = {
            labels: ['Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds'],
            labels1: ['Year', 'Month', 'Week', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second'],
            compactLabels: ['y', 'm', 'w', 'd'],
            whichLabels: null,
            digits: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
            timeSeparator: ':',
            isRTL: false
        };
        this._defaults = {
            until: null,
            since: null,
            timezone: null,
            serverSync: null,
            format: 'dHMS',
            layout: '',
            compact: false,
            significant: 0,
            description: '',
            expiryUrl: '',
            expiryText: '',
            alwaysExpire: false,
            onExpiry: null,
            onTick: null,
            tickInterval: 1
        };
        $.extend(this._defaults, this.regional['']);
        this._serverSyncs = [];
        var c = (typeof Date.now == 'function' ? Date.now : function () {
            return new Date().getTime()
        });
        var d = (window.performance && typeof window.performance.now == 'function');

        function timerCallBack(a) {
            var b = (a < 1e12 ? (d ? (performance.now() + performance.timing.navigationStart) : c()) : a || c());
            if (b - f >= 1000) {
                x._updateTargets();
                f = b
            }
            e(timerCallBack)
        }
        var e = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || null;
        var f = 0;
        if (!e || $.noRequestAnimationFrame) {
            $.noRequestAnimationFrame = null;
            setInterval(function () {
                x._updateTargets()
            }, 980)
        } else {
            f = window.animationStartTime || window.webkitAnimationStartTime || window.mozAnimationStartTime || window.oAnimationStartTime || window.msAnimationStartTime || c();
            e(timerCallBack)
        }
    }
    var Y = 0;
    var O = 1;
    var W = 2;
    var D = 3;
    var H = 4;
    var M = 5;
    var S = 6;
    $.extend(Countdown.prototype, {
        markerClassName: 'hasCountdown',
        propertyName: 'countdown',
        _rtlClass: 'countdown_rtl',
        _sectionClass: 'countdown_section',
        _amountClass: 'countdown_amount',
        _rowClass: 'countdown_row',
        _holdingClass: 'countdown_holding',
        _showClass: 'countdown_show',
        _descrClass: 'countdown_descr',
        _timerTargets: [],
        setDefaults: function (a) {
            this._resetExtraLabels(this._defaults, a);
            $.extend(this._defaults, a || {})
        },
        UTCDate: function (a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i) {
            if (typeof b == 'object' && b.constructor == Date) {
                i = b.getMilliseconds();
                h = b.getSeconds();
                g = b.getMinutes();
                f = b.getHours();
                e = b.getDate();
                c = b.getMonth();
                b = b.getFullYear()
            }
            var d = new Date();
            d.setUTCFullYear(b);
            d.setUTCDate(1);
            d.setUTCMonth(c || 0);
            d.setUTCDate(e || 1);
            d.setUTCHours(f || 0);
            d.setUTCMinutes((g || 0) - (Math.abs(a) < 30 ? a * 60 : a));
            d.setUTCSeconds(h || 0);
            d.setUTCMilliseconds(i || 0);
            return d
        },
        periodsToSeconds: function (a) {
            return a[0] * 31557600 + a[1] * 2629800 + a[2] * 604800 + a[3] * 86400 + a[4] * 3600 + a[5] * 60 + a[6]
        },
        _attachPlugin: function (a, b) {
            a = $(a);
            if (a.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
                return
            }
            var c = {
                options: $.extend({}, this._defaults),
                _periods: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            };
            a.addClass(this.markerClassName).data(this.propertyName, c);
            this._optionPlugin(a, b)
        },
        _addTarget: function (a) {
            if (!this._hasTarget(a)) {
                this._timerTargets.push(a)
            }
        },
        _hasTarget: function (a) {
            return ($.inArray(a, this._timerTargets) > -1)
        },
        _removeTarget: function (b) {
            this._timerTargets = $.map(this._timerTargets, function (a) {
                return (a == b ? null : a)
            })
        },
        _updateTargets: function () {
            for (var i = this._timerTargets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                this._updateCountdown(this._timerTargets[i])
            }
        },
        _optionPlugin: function (a, b, c) {
            a = $(a);
            var d = a.data(this.propertyName);
            if (!b || (typeof b == 'string' && c == null)) {
                var e = b;
                b = (d || {}).options;
                return (b && e ? b[e] : b)
            }
            if (!a.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
                return
            }
            b = b || {};
            if (typeof b == 'string') {
                var e = b;
                b = {};
                b[e] = c
            }
            if (b.layout) {
                b.layout = b.layout.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
            }
            this._resetExtraLabels(d.options, b);
            var f = (d.options.timezone != b.timezone);
            $.extend(d.options, b);
            this._adjustSettings(a, d, b.until != null || b.since != null || f);
            var g = new Date();
            if ((d._since && d._since < g) || (d._until && d._until > g)) {
                this._addTarget(a[0])
            }
            this._updateCountdown(a, d)
        },
        _updateCountdown: function (a, b) {
            var c = $(a);
            b = b || c.data(this.propertyName);
            if (!b) {
                return
            }
            c.html(this._generateHTML(b)).toggleClass(this._rtlClass, b.options.isRTL);
            if ($.isFunction(b.options.onTick)) {
                var d = b._hold != 'lap' ? b._periods : this._calculatePeriods(b, b._show, b.options.significant, new Date());
                if (b.options.tickInterval == 1 || this.periodsToSeconds(d) % b.options.tickInterval == 0) {
                    b.options.onTick.apply(a, [d])
                }
            }
            var e = b._hold != 'pause' && (b._since ? b._now.getTime() < b._since.getTime() : b._now.getTime() >= b._until.getTime());
            if (e && !b._expiring) {
                b._expiring = true;
                if (this._hasTarget(a) || b.options.alwaysExpire) {
                    this._removeTarget(a);
                    if ($.isFunction(b.options.onExpiry)) {
                        b.options.onExpiry.apply(a, [])
                    }
                    if (b.options.expiryText) {
                        var f = b.options.layout;
                        b.options.layout = b.options.expiryText;
                        this._updateCountdown(a, b);
                        b.options.layout = f
                    }
                    if (b.options.expiryUrl) {
                        window.location = b.options.expiryUrl
                    }
                }
                b._expiring = false
            } else if (b._hold == 'pause') {
                this._removeTarget(a)
            }
            c.data(this.propertyName, b)
        },
        _resetExtraLabels: function (a, b) {
            var c = false;
            for (var n in b) {
                if (n != 'whichLabels' && n.match(/[Ll]abels/)) {
                    c = true;
                    break
                }
            }
            if (c) {
                for (var n in a) {
                    if (n.match(/[Ll]abels[02-9]|compactLabels1/)) {
                        a[n] = null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        _adjustSettings: function (a, b, c) {
            var d;
            var e = 0;
            var f = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < this._serverSyncs.length; i++) {
                if (this._serverSyncs[i][0] == b.options.serverSync) {
                    f = this._serverSyncs[i][1];
                    break
                }
            }
            if (f != null) {
                e = (b.options.serverSync ? f : 0);
                d = new Date()
            } else {
                var g = ($.isFunction(b.options.serverSync) ? b.options.serverSync.apply(a, []) : null);
                d = new Date();
                e = (g ? d.getTime() - g.getTime() : 0);
                this._serverSyncs.push([b.options.serverSync, e])
            }
            var h = b.options.timezone;
            h = (h == null ? -d.getTimezoneOffset() : h);
            if (c || (!c && b._until == null && b._since == null)) {
                b._since = b.options.since;
                if (b._since != null) {
                    b._since = this.UTCDate(h, this._determineTime(b._since, null));
                    if (b._since && e) {
                        b._since.setMilliseconds(b._since.getMilliseconds() + e)
                    }
                }
                b._until = this.UTCDate(h, this._determineTime(b.options.until, d));
                if (e) {
                    b._until.setMilliseconds(b._until.getMilliseconds() + e)
                }
            }
            b._show = this._determineShow(b)
        },
        _destroyPlugin: function (a) {
            a = $(a);
            if (!a.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
                return
            }
            this._removeTarget(a[0]);
            a.removeClass(this.markerClassName).empty().removeData(this.propertyName)
        },
        _pausePlugin: function (a) {
            this._hold(a, 'pause')
        },
        _lapPlugin: function (a) {
            this._hold(a, 'lap')
        },
        _resumePlugin: function (a) {
            this._hold(a, null)
        },
        _hold: function (a, b) {
            var c = $.data(a, this.propertyName);
            if (c) {
                if (c._hold == 'pause' && !b) {
                    c._periods = c._savePeriods;
                    var d = (c._since ? '-' : '+');
                    c[c._since ? '_since' : '_until'] = this._determineTime(d + c._periods[0] + 'y' + d + c._periods[1] + 'o' + d + c._periods[2] + 'w' + d + c._periods[3] + 'd' + d + c._periods[4] + 'h' + d + c._periods[5] + 'm' + d + c._periods[6] + 's');
                    this._addTarget(a)
                }
                c._hold = b;
                c._savePeriods = (b == 'pause' ? c._periods : null);
                $.data(a, this.propertyName, c);
                this._updateCountdown(a, c)
            }
        },
        _getTimesPlugin: function (a) {
            var b = $.data(a, this.propertyName);
            return (!b ? null : (b._hold == 'pause' ? b._savePeriods : (!b._hold ? b._periods : this._calculatePeriods(b, b._show, b.options.significant, new Date()))))
        },
        _determineTime: function (k, l) {
            var m = function (a) {
                var b = new Date();
                b.setTime(b.getTime() + a * 1000);
                return b
            };
            var n = function (a) {
                a = a.toLowerCase();
                var b = new Date();
                var c = b.getFullYear();
                var d = b.getMonth();
                var e = b.getDate();
                var f = b.getHours();
                var g = b.getMinutes();
                var h = b.getSeconds();
                var i = /([+-]?[0-9]+)\s*(s|m|h|d|w|o|y)?/g;
                var j = i.exec(a);
                while (j) {
                    switch (j[2] || 's') {
                        case 's':
                            h += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                            break;
                        case 'm':
                            g += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                            break;
                        case 'h':
                            f += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                            break;
                        case 'd':
                            e += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                            break;
                        case 'w':
                            e += parseInt(j[1], 10) * 7;
                            break;
                        case 'o':
                            d += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                            e = Math.min(e, x._getDaysInMonth(c, d));
                            break;
                        case 'y':
                            c += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                            e = Math.min(e, x._getDaysInMonth(c, d));
                            break
                    }
                    j = i.exec(a)
                }
                return new Date(c, d, e, f, g, h, 0)
            };
            var o = (k == null ? l : (typeof k == 'string' ? n(k) : (typeof k == 'number' ? m(k) : k)));
            if (o) o.setMilliseconds(0);
            return o
        },
        _getDaysInMonth: function (a, b) {
            return 32 - new Date(a, b, 32).getDate()
        },
        _normalLabels: function (a) {
            return a
        },
        _generateHTML: function (c) {
            var d = this;
            c._periods = (c._hold ? c._periods : this._calculatePeriods(c, c._show, c.options.significant, new Date()));
            var e = false;
            var f = 0;
            var g = c.options.significant;
            var h = $.extend({}, c._show);
            for (var i = Y; i <= S; i++) {
                e |= (c._show[i] == '?' && c._periods[i] > 0);
                h[i] = (c._show[i] == '?' && !e ? null : c._show[i]);
                f += (h[i] ? 1 : 0);
                g -= (c._periods[i] > 0 ? 1 : 0)
            }
            var j = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
            for (var i = S; i >= Y; i--) {
                if (c._show[i]) {
                    if (c._periods[i]) {
                        j[i] = true
                    } else {
                        j[i] = g > 0;
                        g--
                    }
                }
            }
            var k = (c.options.compact ? c.options.compactLabels : c.options.labels);
            var l = c.options.whichLabels || this._normalLabels;
            var m = function (a) {
                var b = c.options['compactLabels' + l(c._periods[a])];
                return (h[a] ? d._translateDigits(c, c._periods[a]) + (b ? b[a] : k[a]) + ' ' : '')
            };
            var n = function (a) {
                var b = c.options['labels' + l(c._periods[a])];
                return ((!c.options.significant && h[a]) || (c.options.significant && j[a]) ? '<span class="' + x._sectionClass + '">' + '<span class="' + x._amountClass + '">' + d._translateDigits(c, c._periods[a]) + '</span><br/>' + (b ? b[a] : k[a]) + '</span>' : '')
            };
            return (c.options.layout ? this._buildLayout(c, h, c.options.layout, c.options.compact, c.options.significant, j) : ((c.options.compact ? '<span class="' + this._rowClass + ' ' + this._amountClass + (c._hold ? ' ' + this._holdingClass : '') + '">' + m(Y) + m(O) + m(W) + m(D) + (h[H] ? this._minDigits(c, c._periods[H], 2) : '') + (h[M] ? (h[H] ? c.options.timeSeparator : '') + this._minDigits(c, c._periods[M], 2) : '') + (h[S] ? (h[H] || h[M] ? c.options.timeSeparator : '') + this._minDigits(c, c._periods[S], 2) : '') : '<span class="' + this._rowClass + ' ' + this._showClass + (c.options.significant || f) + (c._hold ? ' ' + this._holdingClass : '') + '">' + n(Y) + n(O) + n(W) + n(D) + n(H) + n(M) + n(S)) + '</span>' + (c.options.description ? '<span class="' + this._rowClass + ' ' + this._descrClass + '">' + c.options.description + '</span>' : '')))
        },
        _buildLayout: function (c, d, e, f, g, h) {
            var j = c.options[f ? 'compactLabels' : 'labels'];
            var k = c.options.whichLabels || this._normalLabels;
            var l = function (a) {
                return (c.options[(f ? 'compactLabels' : 'labels') + k(c._periods[a])] || j)[a]
            };
            var m = function (a, b) {
                return c.options.digits[Math.floor(a / b) % 10]
            };
            var o = {
                desc: c.options.description,
                sep: c.options.timeSeparator,
                yl: l(Y),
                yn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[Y], 1),
                ynn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[Y], 2),
                ynnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[Y], 3),
                y1: m(c._periods[Y], 1),
                y10: m(c._periods[Y], 10),
                y100: m(c._periods[Y], 100),
                y1000: m(c._periods[Y], 1000),
                ol: l(O),
                on: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[O], 1),
                onn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[O], 2),
                onnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[O], 3),
                o1: m(c._periods[O], 1),
                o10: m(c._periods[O], 10),
                o100: m(c._periods[O], 100),
                o1000: m(c._periods[O], 1000),
                wl: l(W),
                wn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[W], 1),
                wnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[W], 2),
                wnnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[W], 3),
                w1: m(c._periods[W], 1),
                w10: m(c._periods[W], 10),
                w100: m(c._periods[W], 100),
                w1000: m(c._periods[W], 1000),
                dl: l(D),
                dn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[D], 1),
                dnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[D], 2),
                dnnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[D], 3),
                d1: m(c._periods[D], 1),
                d10: m(c._periods[D], 10),
                d100: m(c._periods[D], 100),
                d1000: m(c._periods[D], 1000),
                hl: l(H),
                hn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[H], 1),
                hnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[H], 2),
                hnnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[H], 3),
                h1: m(c._periods[H], 1),
                h10: m(c._periods[H], 10),
                h100: m(c._periods[H], 100),
                h1000: m(c._periods[H], 1000),
                ml: l(M),
                mn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[M], 1),
                mnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[M], 2),
                mnnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[M], 3),
                m1: m(c._periods[M], 1),
                m10: m(c._periods[M], 10),
                m100: m(c._periods[M], 100),
                m1000: m(c._periods[M], 1000),
                sl: l(S),
                sn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[S], 1),
                snn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[S], 2),
                snnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[S], 3),
                s1: m(c._periods[S], 1),
                s10: m(c._periods[S], 10),
                s100: m(c._periods[S], 100),
                s1000: m(c._periods[S], 1000)
            };
            var p = e;
            for (var i = Y; i <= S; i++) {
                var q = 'yowdhms'.charAt(i);
                var r = new RegExp('\\{' + q + '<\\}([\\s\\S]*)\\{' + q + '>\\}', 'g');
                p = p.replace(r, ((!g && d[i]) || (g && h[i]) ? '$1' : ''))
            }
            $.each(o, function (n, v) {
                var a = new RegExp('\\{' + n + '\\}', 'g');
                p = p.replace(a, v)
            });
            return p
        },
        _minDigits: function (a, b, c) {
            b = '' + b;
            if (b.length >= c) {
                return this._translateDigits(a, b)
            }
            b = '0000000000' + b;
            return this._translateDigits(a, b.substr(b.length - c))
        },
        _translateDigits: function (b, c) {
            return ('' + c).replace(/[0-9]/g, function (a) {
                return b.options.digits[a]
            })
        },
        _determineShow: function (a) {
            var b = a.options.format;
            var c = [];
            c[Y] = (b.match('y') ? '?' : (b.match('Y') ? '!' : null));
            c[O] = (b.match('o') ? '?' : (b.match('O') ? '!' : null));
            c[W] = (b.match('w') ? '?' : (b.match('W') ? '!' : null));
            c[D] = (b.match('d') ? '?' : (b.match('D') ? '!' : null));
            c[H] = (b.match('h') ? '?' : (b.match('H') ? '!' : null));
            c[M] = (b.match('m') ? '?' : (b.match('M') ? '!' : null));
            c[S] = (b.match('s') ? '?' : (b.match('S') ? '!' : null));
            return c
        },
        _calculatePeriods: function (c, d, e, f) {
            c._now = f;
            c._now.setMilliseconds(0);
            var g = new Date(c._now.getTime());
            if (c._since) {
                if (f.getTime() < c._since.getTime()) {
                    c._now = f = g
                } else {
                    f = c._since
                }
            } else {
                g.setTime(c._until.getTime());
                if (f.getTime() > c._until.getTime()) {
                    c._now = f = g
                }
            }
            var h = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
            if (d[Y] || d[O]) {
                var i = x._getDaysInMonth(f.getFullYear(), f.getMonth());
                var j = x._getDaysInMonth(g.getFullYear(), g.getMonth());
                var k = (g.getDate() == f.getDate() || (g.getDate() >= Math.min(i, j) && f.getDate() >= Math.min(i, j)));
                var l = function (a) {
                    return (a.getHours() * 60 + a.getMinutes()) * 60 + a.getSeconds()
                };
                var m = Math.max(0, (g.getFullYear() - f.getFullYear()) * 12 + g.getMonth() - f.getMonth() + ((g.getDate() < f.getDate() && !k) || (k && l(g) < l(f)) ? -1 : 0));
                h[Y] = (d[Y] ? Math.floor(m / 12) : 0);
                h[O] = (d[O] ? m - h[Y] * 12 : 0);
                f = new Date(f.getTime());
                var n = (f.getDate() == i);
                var o = x._getDaysInMonth(f.getFullYear() + h[Y], f.getMonth() + h[O]);
                if (f.getDate() > o) {
                    f.setDate(o)
                }
                f.setFullYear(f.getFullYear() + h[Y]);
                f.setMonth(f.getMonth() + h[O]);
                if (n) {
                    f.setDate(o)
                }
            }
            var p = Math.floor((g.getTime() - f.getTime()) / 1000);
            var q = function (a, b) {
                h[a] = (d[a] ? Math.floor(p / b) : 0);
                p -= h[a] * b
            };
            q(W, 604800);
            q(D, 86400);
            q(H, 3600);
            q(M, 60);
            q(S, 1);
            if (p > 0 && !c._since) {
                var r = [1, 12, 4.3482, 7, 24, 60, 60];
                var s = S;
                var t = 1;
                for (var u = S; u >= Y; u--) {
                    if (d[u]) {
                        if (h[s] >= t) {
                            h[s] = 0;
                            p = 1
                        }
                        if (p > 0) {
                            h[u]++;
                            p = 0;
                            s = u;
                            t = 1
                        }
                    }
                    t *= r[u]
                }
            }
            if (e) {
                for (var u = Y; u <= S; u++) {
                    if (e && h[u]) {
                        e--
                    } else if (!e) {
                        h[u] = 0
                    }
                }
            }
            return h
        }
    });
    var w = ['getTimes'];

    function isNotChained(a, b) {
        if (a == 'option' && (b.length == 0 || (b.length == 1 && typeof b[0] == 'string'))) {
            return true
        }
        return $.inArray(a, w) > -1
    }
    $.fn.countdown = function (a) {
        var b = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        if (isNotChained(a, b)) {
            return x['_' + a + 'Plugin'].apply(x, [this[0]].concat(b))
        }
        return this.each(function () {
            if (typeof a == 'string') {
                if (!x['_' + a + 'Plugin']) {
                    throw 'Unknown command: ' + a;
                }
                x['_' + a + 'Plugin'].apply(x, [this].concat(b))
            } else {
                x._attachPlugin(this, a || {})
            }
        })
    };
    var x = $.countdown = new Countdown()
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle!

Comment: +1 for the title. "*Countdown... the time is running out..*" precious.

Comment: Wow, that is a *massive* wall of code. Can you reformat that for us?

Comment: Whoever edited it onto one line actually made it worse.  Well done the person who ran it through a prettifier.

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript file called custom.js

Here is the code to find you will see the date you have to modify,

Additional information regarding this plugin can be found http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

```
// Countdown //
$('#countdown').countdown({
    until: new Date(2014, 10 - 1, 9), // new Date(year, mth - 1, day, hr, min, sec) - date/time to count down to 
    // or numeric for seconds offset, or string for unit offset(s): 
    // 'Y' years, 'O' months, 'W' weeks, 'D' days, 'H' hours, 'M' minutes, 'S' seconds 
    timezone: -4, // The timezone (hours or minutes from GMT) for the target times, or null for client local 
    layout: '{d<}<div class="span3"><div class="digit-container">{dn}<span class="label-container">{dl}</span></div></div>{d>}{h<}<div class="span3"><div class="digit-container">{hn}<span class="label-container">{hl}</span></div></div>{h>}{m<}<div class="span3"><div class="digit-container">{mn}<span class="label-container">{ml}</span></div></div>{m>}{s<}<div class="span3"><div class="digit-container">{sn}<span class="label-container">{sl}</span></div></div>{s>}',
    timeSeparator: '', // Separator for time periods 
    isRTL: false, // True for right-to-left languages, false for left-to-right 
    format: 'dHMS', // Format for display - upper case for always, lower case only if non-zero,
    // 'Y' years, 'O' months, 'W' weeks, 'D' days, 'H' hours, 'M' minutes, 'S' seconds
    alwaysExpire: true, // True to trigger onExpiry even if never counted down 
    onExpiry: liftOff // Callback when the countdown expires - 
    // receives no parameters and 'this' is the containing division 
});
```

Comment: Hi Marko, so ichange it to the date using the formula, but it is now saying like twice as long....hmm im a little flumoxed, :) - from when does the countdown start from!